# Trying to break out of a string loop

Tags: c++, string, loops, break

Okay so I've been troubleshooting an issue I have with my "process" function below. When I submit my code, I get the correct output but my loop never ends. When I try to end the loop, I get no output. I know how to end the loop if the variable is an integer but the string is throwing me for a loop. I'm new to this, and I'm sure the solution is probably right in front of my face. Thanks for the help.

```
int process()
{
double price = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        int items = 0;
        string order = "";

        cout << "Enter your order string: ";
        cin >> order;

        items = findItem(order);

        if (items < 0)
        {
            cout << order << " is invalid. Skipping it.\n";
            break;

        }
            cout << names[items] << ": $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << prices[items] << endl;
            price += prices[items];
    }
    cout << "Total: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << price;



}




#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXPRODUCTS = 100;
string names[MAXPRODUCTS];
double prices[MAXPRODUCTS];
string codes[MAXPRODUCTS];
int numProducts = 0;

void readConfiguration()
{
    int i =0;
    ifstream finput("menu.txt");
    while(finput >> codes[i] >> names[i] >> prices[i])
    {
        i++;
        numProducts = i;
    }

}

//return valid index if the item is found, return -1 otherwise.
int findItem(string inputCode)
{
    for(int i =0; i<numProducts; i++)
    {
        if(inputCode == codes[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

// read order string like "A1 A1 E1 E2 S1" and generate the restaurant bill.
// Output the item name and price in each line, total in the final line.
int process()
{
    string order = "";

    while(true)
    {
        int items = 0;
        cout << "Enter your order string: ";
        cin >> order;

        items = findItem(order);

        if (items < 0)
        {
            cout << order << " is invalid. Skipping it.\n";
            continue;

        }
        else
            cout << names[items] << ": $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << prices[items] << endl;
    }
    return 0;


}

int main()
{
    readConfiguration();
    process();
}
```

Comment: 1) "_When I submit my code, I get the correct output but my loop never ends._" Which loop? 2) Do you mean the loop `while(true)`? How do you "try" to break out of it? There is no `break` statement, nor there is a `return` statement inside it.

Comment: sorry I thought I specified when I said the "process function" but yes, the while(true) loop. Currently the code works it just repeats forever, but if I try to break out of it, it returns no output at all. So that's my confusion.

Comment: 1) So, please show the code, that you try to break out of the loop of, Currently, this code doesn't even try to do that, so the immediate answer is: if you want to break out of loop, just break out of the loop.. 2) "_but if I try to break out of it, it returns no output at all._" Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out, why that is?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, okay I edited my original post with the break in the loop. It's at the top of the coded portion of my post. This issue with this is that it breaks out of the loop when the "order" is wrong, but it should just skip it and move to the next value.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I don't know how to end the loop when no more "order " values are there to be processed

Comment: You always control your read loop with the read function itself. You are inherently testing the *Stream State*. See [std::basic_ios](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios)

Answer (score 0):

**try to edit `while(true)` to `while(cin >> order)`**

```
while(cin >> order)
{
    int items = 0;
    cout << "Enter your order string: ";

    items = findItem(order);

    if (items < 0)
    {
        cout << order << " is invalid. Skipping it.\n";
        continue;

    }
    else
        cout << names[items] << ": $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << prices[items] << endl;
}
```